# Node.js server file console.log() not showing when starting server with Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am starting my node application using grunt command. My Gruntfile.js is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
       nodemon: {
           dev: {
               script: 'server.js'
           }
       },

       watch: {
             css: {
                 files: ['src/css/*.scss'],
                 tasks: ['sass:dev']
             },
             js: {
                 files: ['src/js/*.js'],
                 tasks: ['uglify:dev']
             }
       },    

       concurrent: {
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            },
            tasks: ['nodemon','watch']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['concurrent']);
};
```

When I run the application typing `grunt` I get the following output:

```
C:\Projects\SocialMeal>grunt
Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...


[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

Then every console.log() call at server.js is not shown. If I start the app using `node server.js` the console.log() messages are shown.

Any hint?

Comment: Your `server.js` file is inside `src/js` folder?

Comment: No. It is at the app root dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it thanks to greuze. The problem was nodemon version. Changed it to 1.11.0 and the console.log outputs works now.

Simply removed the current version installed:

```
npm uninstall grunt-nodemon
```

And changed package.json:

```
"grunt-nodemon": "~1.10.0",
```

Comment: Yes I was about to post this link, that shows the issue (it had bit me before too!) https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/153

Answer (score 0):

I do get `console.log` outputs.

I have an `server.js` file with content:

```
let name = 'Peter';

console.log(`My name is: ${name}`);
```

I used your Gruntfile.js.

I get this output after running `grunt`:

```
Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...
    Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
    [nodemon] 1.11.0
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching: *.*
    [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
    My name is: Peter
    [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Note that there is the console.log output. Are you sure your process is not stuck anywhere?

Comment: Thanks  so far. Let me take a look.

Comment: Found it thanks to greuze. The problem was nodemon version. Changed it to 1.11.0 and the console.log outputs works now.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)